# Typescript + Express = locked in a configuration loop

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I want to use ES6 modules in my app.

If I set `"module": "es2020"` or `"module": "esnext"` I get error `To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`

So I set the `"type" : "module"` in my `package.json` and get error saying `Unknown file extension ".ts"` So I can't use it. I can't use `.mjs` extension in Typescript too.

So I set `"module": "commonjs"` and `"esModuleInterop": true` and I can use ES6 modules with Typescript. But then I want to use `import.meta` and I get error saying that `the 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'esnext', or 'system'.`

I ran full circle. Is there a configuration that will allow me to use Typescript with Node without compromises? It's just `import.meta` now, but I am not sure what other features will be locked with this setup.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by using experimental feature. Instead of running ts-node command to run the code I used:

`TS_NODE_PROJECT='./tsconfig.json' node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/index.ts`

This allows me to use `"type": "module"` and `"module": "esnext"` together with Typescript, and I have both ES6 imports and access to `import.meta`.

I get a warning in console that the feature is experimental and could change at any time, so it's good to keep that in mind and reconsider if it's worth it.

Comment: i am pretty new to this but i don't think the `tsconfig` will accept a key of `"type"` at all. did you mean `"types": [...]`?